# Workflow stops suddenly when creating channel

Tags: nextflow

This is my code:

process descargaSRA {

```
publishDir("sra_files", mode: 'copy')

input:
    path sra_file

output:
    file "SRR*"

script:
    """
    ids_sra=\$(cat ${sra_file})
    for id in \${ids_sra}
    do
        prefetch \${id} -O .
        mv "\$id/\$id.sra" .
        rm -r "\$id"
    done
    """
```

}

process convert_to_fastq {

```
input:
    file sra_content 

output:
    path "fastq_files"

script:
    """
    fastq-dump --split-files ${sra_content} -O fastq_files
    """
```

}

process filter_reads {

```
publishDir("fastp_files", mode: 'copy')

input:
tuple val(id), val(fastq_files)
output:
tuple val(id), path("clean_*")

script:
"""
echo "Processing ${id} reads"

fastp -i ${fastq_files[0]} -I ${fastq_files[1]} -o clean_${id}_1.fastq -O clean_${id}_2.fastq --cut_tail --cut_window_size 5 --cut_mean_quality 30
"""
```

}

process indexing_reference {

```
publishDir("index_reference", mode: "copy")
input:
    path reference
    path fastp

output:
    path "genome*"

script:
    """
    bwa index ${reference} -p genome
    """
```

}

process mapping_to_reference{
publishDir("bam_files",mode:"copy")

```
input:
    path genome
    tuple val(id), val(clean_fastq)
output:
    path "*.sorted.bam"
script:
    """
    bwa mem genome ${clean_fastq[0]} ${clean_fastq[1]} > ${id}.sam
    samtools view ${id}.sam -o ${id}.bam
    samtools sort ${id}.bam -o ${id}_sorted.bam
    samtools index ${id}_sorted.bam
    """
```

}

workflow {

```
input_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.sra_file)
reference = Channel.fromPath(params.reference)


sra_ch = descargaSRA(input_ch)

fastq_ch = convert_to_fastq(sra_ch)

"This channel will group the fastq files by ID"
fastq_paths = Channel.fromFilePairs("${fastq_ch}/SRR*_{1,2}.fastq")

fastp_ch = filter_reads(fastq_paths)
genome = indexing_reference(reference,fastp_ch)
map_ch = mapping_to_reference(genome,fastp_ch)
```

}

I will give some context. The process descargaSRA gets a file with accession names and downloads the .sra files, while the process convert_to_fastq turns those .sra into .fastq files. However, for each .sra there are two fastq (SRR*_1.fastq and SRR*_2.fastq) and this is creating a problem because when correcting and mapping I need those two files together.

For this reason, I thought of using a new channel with the method .fromFilePairs so as to link the SRR_ID with both fastq files. Despite this, when running the pipeline the process stops as soon as convert_to_fastq ends, so I need to run the pipeline again to get the final results. I guess that fastq_paths is not directly connected to fastq_ch given that I'm only using the value and not the channel itself, but I couldn't come up with any other solution.

Thanks for your help, I am trying to learn this new tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulate your `convert_to_fastq` output channel in such a way this it has a `[sampleID, file.fastq]` format. Then call `groupTuple()` on that channel to pair your fastq's per sample.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem that you have paired files. It looks like you are already handling them partially: both `filter_reads` and `mapping_to_reference` processes assume, that your fastq input is a list of (at least) 2 files.

However, those two files are not in the output of `convert_to_fastq`, instead the entire output-directory of `fastq-dump` is (meaning that you only have a single entry instead of all files). If you would specify the output differently:

```
input:
    file sra_content 

output:
    path "fastq_files/*"

script:
    """
    fastq-dump --split-files ${sra_content} -O fastq_files
    """
```

You will instead get a list containing all files written by fastq-dump. So you don't need to use `fromFilePairs` and can use `fastq_ch` directly as input channel for `filter_reads` process - if it's safe to assume that you always just get 2 files otherwise you need to define the output pattern for each file you want to use separately and return a tuple of paths by this process.